# Image cannot be loaded

Tags: php, mysql, image

I was installing an open source library management (based on PHP and MySQL) in one of my subdomain (here's the link http://perpustakaanbeta.atdikbudlondon.org/).

I am having problem with the icon and background image,as you can see from the website. Take the background image as the example. It is not suppose to be just plain black. By default, the developer has leaved us some images within the source. And I am sure the path to the intended source,i.e. the image,is correct. I have tried to put a direct URL of any random image (http://www.imageshack.com/blabla/bla.jpg) as the input for ,it worked. But,if I changed it back,it didn't work.

If anyone know what might have gone wrong,please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: All images referenced in your document respond with "403 Forbidden".

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected "403 Forbidden" errors on software that you've just uploaded to your website are often caused by incorrect file permissions.

Log into your shell account or file manager and make sure the ownership and permissions of these files are set correctly. Set the permission of files to `0644` and folders to `0755`.